# Wiring question at POTS DEMARC point

Tags: cable, telephony

This is my first time using stack exchange. Let me give a brief backstory. I work at a company, we have multiple phone lines. One of the phone lines was cancelled but had a phone hooked up to it. I am attempting to move that phone to the an existing but open number that we have from the POTS provider.

Onto the question... I am looking at the box provided by POTS service provider. There is a typical 66 punch down block but I am working in the box next to that where it looks like the wires are punched down again in some sort of goo? I've attached two pictures down below because I doubt that I am explaining it correctly.

[image: First picture of goo punchdown]

[image: Second picture of goo punchdown]

I am unsure of how to make a connection with the goo in there. I have tried putting the wires in all sorts of ways. I have tried looking this question up online but was unable to find any sort of information. Specifically I am working the the brown pair that is on the bottom row to the most right. They are in the spot they need to go in and they feel somewhat snug in there, but I believe I am not making a solid connection. If anyone  has any experience/ knowledge of this and can tell make how to make a connection here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The goo is surely dielectric grease.  I have never seen it used in this way myself; is this in a damp or corrosive environment?

Comment: I assume you need to pull out white bit you would see two holes to push into. Insert cables inside and push back together with wires into block.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is some type of electrical grease, to keep moisture out. Maybe try trace the pair from the block you are wanting to connect into, trace that pair back to the cable coming into the distribution block, cut it out from back of block and use scotch locks, or soemthing similar, to crimp your pair to the POTS pair.

You could get into trouble by to the main ISP who owns the cable into the POTS however, so I take no responsibility fro your actions.